# Do items drop based on class used or most used?

Tags: team-fortress-2

After accuiring my third 'Dead Ringer' in as many hours while playing tf2, I was wondering,

does the item dropped correlate with:

- Absolutely nothing (completely random)
- The class you have been using
- The classes you have been most often killing/interacting with

If so this can be used easily to manipulate drops :) although I do doubt this is the case

Comment: You can always use the crafting system to make items to the class you want.

Comment: @Celta i know but with scrap metal being made with two class items and me trying to get specific class items anyway it would have sped things up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The item drop system is a random process.**

The class you are or the class you play most often have no effect on what item is dropped.

**Pros:**

> - Allows new and old players alike to earn unlockable weapons by investing playtime
> - Allows players to play as any class

**Cons:**

> - Many players receive unwanted duplicates
>
>   - This issue was resolved by the introduction of the crafting and trading system

More information and source: [Item drop system - Team Fortress Wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_drop_system)

Comment: hmm, this confirms my suspicions, and also explains why my server consisting of 15 scout bots didn't yeild anything interesting yesterday. Thanks :)